# 100 users upload file at the same time jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load

I have the following scenario:

create 100 users, then all users send a file (each one a unique and different file selected from an excel containing 100 file names) at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Record a single file upload event using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). During the recording [make sure that the file you will be uploading lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) as well.
2. Parameterize recorded hard-coded filename using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config). Keep in mind that you need to either copy your files to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation or make sure that your CSV file contains **full** paths to the files you will need to upload.
3. Set number of threads to `100` in your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
4. Add a [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which performs the file upload and set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to `100`

Comment: what value should i put in thread properties "ramp up" period and "loop count"?

Comment: Ramp-up - no matter, less is better as you will have to wait till all 100 users will be kicked off. Loop count - according to your test plan, 1 - you will have 100 uploads, 2 - 200, etc.